# How to find books that your favourite author has endored or "blurbed"?

Tags: publishing

Is there some way to search online, for what books someone has endorsed with a blurb? A service, website (amazon, goodreads) or perhaps some clever google query construction or DDG-fu to search thereof?

Since publishers use it as promotion, it would seem to make sense that they'd make this advertisement available in other ways than only on the back cover.

Strictly as an illustrative example only, and **not** asking for lists or recommendations specific to this example: Larry Niven and Vernor Vinge are my favourite authors, and they both contributed a back-cover blurb endorsing Karl Schroeder's novel "Sun of Suns" (on a later novel in the series, "The Sunless Countries").
But I only noticed that by chance, when browsing (very) randomly in a library.

**EDIT** [this article](https://medium.com/sci-fi-strange/excuse-me-for-blurbing-7e88e34afe63) says that Amazon doesn't allow reviews by authors (or blurbs or recommendations, I guess) because it's too easily abused:

> Amazon.com [banned authors from reviewing the books of other authors](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/books/booknews/9738552/Author-backlash-over-Amazons-new-online-review-crackdown.html) due to conflicts of interest. Essentially, Amazon figured authors would either praise the works of their friends or pan the authors they hate. Not that this is totally true, but there’s enough truth to understand Amazon’s actions.

Comment: This is off topic, definitely, but if there's an answer I'd like to know it.

Comment: Thing is... it's a request for a *method*, not a specific list; the latter seems to be what that rule is more oriented toward preventing. (Note the "Feel free to ask about people's favorites in chat" part.) If such a search query or database expressly created for the purpose existed, the above question would have a simple, objective solution. It was previously asked [in 2013 on MetaFilter](https://ask.metafilter.com/244567/How-do-I-search-for-books-that-have-been-blurbed-by-certain-authors) and [in 2016 on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12307337), without success.

Comment: @JacobC yes, the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) says the reason to not ask for lists is to "Avoid questions that are **primarily opinion-based**, or that are likely to **generate discussion** rather than answers.", and this request for a method is neither. How could I rewrite the question to emphasise this? Though I do admit it *is* something of a meta-question.

Comment: @hyperpallium You're welcome to ask this over at our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe)